# How do I add time length to fadeIn();?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fade

Using JQuery fadeIn(); I want to add a time length to it.  I am currently using it this way:

```
    var transition = 'slow';
    var target1 = $('.div1');
    target1.delay(1500).fadeIn();
```

It works fine but I would like to make the div start showing slowly, so after it loads the div should slowing start showing.  How can I add a time for it using what I have below? I googled but couldn't find anything related to this.  Perhaps I should be looking at something else?

Comment: The fun thing about the jQuery API is how easy it is to search, basically: `'http://api.jquery.com/' + methodName`, so:  [`fadeIn()` is at `http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the jquery Docs - http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

```
.fadeIn( [duration ] [, complete ] )
```

You need this-

```
 target1.fadeIn(1500);
```